# Correlation significance for non-zero null hypothesis using R

Tags: r, correlation

I'm testing the correlation between two variables:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- x + x * 1:20
cor.test(x, y, method = c("spearman"))
```

which gives:

```
Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  x and y 
S = 54, p-value = 6.442e-06
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
   rho 
0.9594
```

The p-value is testing the null hypothesis that the correlation is zero. Is there an R function that will allow me to test a different null hypothesis - say that the correlation is less than or equal to 0.3?

Comment: seems to me that this would be difficult for a rank correlation procedure.  You might want to ask the question (without the R-specific tag) on stack exchange ...

Comment: I think @BenBolker meant stats.stackexchange.com, just so you know.

Comment: I'm short on brain cells right now, but wouldn't you start out by actually calculating the correlation coefficient on your two data sets, and follow that up with either a null-test or a Bayesian estimate of the quality of your calculation?

Comment: Maybe you find the answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14220/3094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't say in the question, but if you can live with Pearson assumptions (bivariate normal), you can just look to the upper bound of the confidence interval. Any null hypothesis like yours that is greater than that would be rejected at p<0.05.

```
> cor.test(x, y, method = c("pearson"))$conf
[1] 0.7757901 0.9629837
```

Comment: Yes, i'd thought about that for Pearson's coefficient, but unfortunately I have several outliers in my real data and therefore I think rho would be more appropriate. I don't know if there's a way to generate confidence intervals for rho.

Comment: You can use bootstrap to generate confidence intervals for rho, see the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bootstrap to calculate the confidence interval for rho:

1) Make function to extract the estimate of the cor.test (remember to put indices so the boot can sample the data):

```
rho <- function(x, y, indices){
  rho <- cor.test(x[indices], y[indices],  method = c("spearman"))
  return(rho$estimate)
}
```

2) Use the `boot` package to bootstrap your estimate:

```
library(boot)    
boot.rho <- boot(x ,y=y, rho, R=1000)
```

3) Take the confidence interval:

```
boot.ci(boot.rho)
```